# Android multilanguage support: string formatting issue due to different placeholder counts

Tags: android, xml, string, localization, string-formatting

I'm making a french Android app and I'm trying to support English.

I use "placeholders" to format my strings, so I can adapt them to male and female users. For example, this string in my `strings.xml` file:

```
<string name="encouraging_comment">
    Les %1$s sont compliqué%2$ss...
</string>
```

will become "Les **hommes** sont compliqués" ("**Men** are complicated") or "Les **femmes** sont compliqué**e**s" ("**Women** are complicated").

And there lies my problem. The string translation, as follows...

```
<string name="encouraging_comment">
    %1$s are complicated...
</string>
```

...needs only one placeholder, when the french equivalent needs two.

How can I manage this issue ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just omit the second placeholder from the English template string and use an empty string for the second argument (or any other string, it doesn't matter, the value will be ignored) when you render the string:

XML:

```
<string name="encouraging_comment">
    %1$s are complicated...
</string>
```

Java:

```
getString(R.string.encouraging_comment, "women", "");
getString(R.string.encouraging_comment, "men", "");
```

This works because it's not an error if there are *more* arguments than placeholders, only if there are *fewer* arguments than placeholders.

I'm assuming that you'll have some kind of table or mapping where you look up the placeholder values based on language and gender. In pseudo-code:

```
(French,  Female) -> ("femmes", "e")
(French,  Male)   -> ("hommes", "" )
(English, Female) -> ("women",  "" )
(English, Male)   -> ("men",    "" )
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, you can do this by adding check in your code like

```
String result;
if ( Locale.getDefault().getLanguage().equals("en")){  // examples "en", "fr", "sp"
      result= getString(R.string.encouraging_comment, myString);
    }
    else{
      result= getString(R.string.encouraging_comment, myString, myStringTwo);
    }
textView.setText(result);
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: Sadly this gives me a _Wrong argument count_ error in the "english" block; I guess it counts the arguments for the default string.

Comment: @Eva can you share the error or your code snipet how are you using this code

Comment: Funny thing: with this code
`if(getString(R.string.locale).equals(Constantes.LOCALE_EN)) {s=res.getString(R.string.str, "...","");}`
The error/warning reads "Wrong argument count, format string `encouraging_comment` requires 2 but format call supplies 1".
While with this one
`if(getString(R.string.locale).equals(Constantes.LOCALE_EN)) {s=res.getString(R.string.str, "...","");}`
it goes "Wrong argument count, format string `encouraging_comment` requires 1 but format call supplies 2".

In both cases though the app works w/out crashing!

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is create a string `locale` in your `strings.xml`

for **English Strings.xml**

```
<string name="locale">En</string>
```

for **French Strings.xml**

```
<string name="locale">Fr</string>
```

Then while setting string

```
 switch (getString(R.string.locale)) {
            case "Fr":
                //set your string for French
                break;
            case "En":
                //set your string for English 
                break;
        }
```